# Create a table of results using 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in a mysql database that I want to query:

```
courses (id, course_name)
college_courses (id, college_id, course_id, num_of_courses)
student_courses (id, course_id, college_id)
```

I am trying to pass an array of course ids to the query and a college id. I want to create a result set to show the name of each course (based on the ids I pass), how many courses the college (e.g. id=8) has access to and how many of each course have been assigned to students. I've tried building a query using joins and sub queries. This is what I have right now but the numbers for courses assigned to colleges and students are all wrong:

```
SELECT
   courses.course_name,
   COALESCE(SUM( 
   CASE
      WHEN
         college_courses.college_id = 8 
      THEN
         college_courses.num_of_courses 
      ELSE
         0 
   END
), 0) AS total, COUNT(
   CASE
      WHEN
         student_courses.college_id = 8 
      THEN
         student_courses.id 
      ELSE
         0 
   END
) AS usedCourses 
FROM
   courses 
   LEFT JOIN
      college_courses 
      ON college_courses.course_id = courses.id 
   LEFT JOIN
      student_courses 
      ON student_courses.course_id = courses.id 
WHERE
   courses.id IN 
   (
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
   )
GROUP BY
   courses.courseid
```

Comment: Please also provide .sql table, so we can check with query.

Comment: Apologises, but there doesn't seem to be any option for me to edit my question, Tried commenting my sample data but it's too long for a comment.